# How to enable metrics in Minishift v1.5.1 for Windows

Tags: windows, docker, openshift, metrics, minishift

I started Minishift v1.5.1 in Windows 10 Pro informing the parameter "--metrics", and by chance the metrics were not enabled.

Is there any extra option for it? 
See console:

```
C:\>minishift start --metrics
Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'hyperv' hypervisor...
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... OK
-- Checking Docker version ... OK
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ...
   Deleted existing OpenShift container
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v1.5.1 image ... OK
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... OK
-- Checking for available ports ... OK
-- Checking type of volume mount ...
   Using Docker shared volumes for OpenShift volumes
-- Creating host directories ... OK
-- Finding server IP ...
   Using 192.168.1.162 as the server IP
-- Starting OpenShift container ...
   Starting OpenShift using container 'origin'
   Waiting for API server to start listening
   OpenShift server started
-- Removing temporary directory ... OK
-- Checking container networking ... OK
-- Server Information ...
   OpenShift server started.
   The server is accessible via web console at:
       https://192.168.1.162:8443

   To login as administrator:
       oc login -u system:admin
```

Comment: The enabling of metrics is optional, as right now from what I have seen, sometimes it doesn't actually start up properly. Part of the reason as to why it may fail based on what I have seen, is how slow of an Internet connection you have. If pulling down of images takes a long time, bits that are expected to be started, may not be started before other bits expect them to be and this can cause metrics to not start properly. Also, using metrics can require more resources, so make sure you override the amount of memory and CPU allocated by Minishift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graham's answer [How to enable metrics in Minishift v1.5.1 for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001364/how-to-enable-metrics-in-minishift-v1-5-1-for-windows#comment76981180_45001364) is basically correct, I just would like to add a couple of clarifications.

There is no Minishift version v1.5.1. 1.5.1 is the version of OpenShift which gets provisioned. You can determine the Minishift version you are running via:

```
$minishift version
```

Looking at the output, it seems that you restarted an existing instance of Minishift. Even though metrics might not even provision based on your network speed (as discussed in Graham's answer), one should still see something in the logs). If you have an existing Minishift instance, make sure to delete it first, prior to starting with metrics enabled:

```
$ minishift delete
$ minishift start --metrics
```

Comment: You're right, I deleted and recreated Minishift again, and metrics were enabled. Tks!